# No fixed point problem for iterations

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function that is not a polynomial of degree 1 or degree 0 , where $z$ is a complex number.

Let $f(z,1) = f(z)$ and let $f(z,n) = f(f(z,n-1))$.

Let $g(f,1)$ be the amount of distinct complex fixpoints of $f(z,1)$.

More general let $g(f,n)$ be the amount of distinct complex fixpoints of $f(z,n)$.

Let $G(f,n)$ = $g(f,1)$ + $g(f,2)$ $+ ... +$ $g(f,n)$

What is an example $f(z)$ such that $G(f,30)$ = 0 ?

Comment: By "nonlinear" do you mean in the sense of linear maps, or linear polynomials?

Comment: Briefly: a linear map is a function $f$ such that $f(\lambda x + \mu y) = \lambda f(x) + \mu f(y)$, whereas a linear polynomial is just a polynomial of degree 1. I assume you mean the latter (the only linear maps that are also entire functions are multiplication by a constant), but you ought to be clear.

Comment: @ Ben : Thanks you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are none.

Suppose $f$ is an entire function and both $f$ and $f(\cdot,2)$ lack fixed points.  Consider
$$q(z) = \frac{f(z) - f(z,2)}{f(z) - z}$$
Since the denominator is never $0$, this is an entire function.  It never takes the values $0$ (because $f(z) - f(z,2) = 0$ would mean $f(z)$ is a fixed point of $f$) or $1$
(because $f(z) - f(z,2) = f(z) - z$ would mean $z$ is a fixed point of $f(\cdot,2)$).  By 
Little Picard it is constant: $q(z) \equiv c$ where $c \notin \{0,1\}$. But then $z = c^{-1} (f(f(z)) + (c-1) f(z))$ implies that $f$ is one-to-one, and the only one-to-one entire functions are polynomials of degree $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see that $q(z)=c$.
Could you explain why f is one-to-one ?

Comment: If $f(z_1) = f(z_2)$, then 
$$z_1 = c^{-1} (f(f(z_1)) + (c-1) f(z_1)) = c^{-1} (f(f(z_2)) + (c-1) f(z_2)) = z_2$$

Comment: Ah yes ! Thank you.

Comment: I was wondering about non-entire functions ... I think it applies to all taylor series. And others. Im dreaming about fractals now.

Comment: You have to worry about domains.  For example, a branch of $\sqrt{z}$ with branch cut on $[0,\infty)$ maps ${\mathbb C} \backslash [0,\infty)$ into itself and has no fixed or periodic points.